# Converting .tiff image from Google Earth Engine to PNG format

Tags: tiff, google-earth-engine, geotiff

I have exported the image from Google Earth Engine and trying to visualize it but It is showing black/Nothing. How to visualize the downloaded .tiff image in valid format [PNG] which can be seen in visualization tool using python.

1. Can we convert this tiff image to png format which can be seen?
2. Which visualization tool we can use to visualize the images?

code.

```
import os
import ee
import geemap

"""Autentication layer"""

# Trigger the authentication flow.
ee.Authenticate()
# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()

"""Creating Path to save Image in Local pc"""

out_dir = os.path.expanduser("Provide the path where you need to save in local PC")

#Creating the Lat/Long and setting band with to extract "multi-spectral imaging "
loc = ee.Geometry.Point(-1.261182, 51.759641)
collection = (
    ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
    .filterBounds(loc)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-02-02')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains("system:band_names", 'B3'))
    .select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'])  
)

"""Creating the Imgae Collection block"""
geemap.download_ee_image_collection(collection, out_dir, scale=10)
```

Comment: I don't see the image in your post, nor any code that creates or downloads one. Please click [edit] and provide your [mre]. Thanks.

Comment: HI @MarkSetchell: I have downloaded the image which is quite large in size. I have downloaded the images using Google Earth Engine, and I wanted to convert into .png format but It is coming black, so I thought to use any specific visualisation like QGis which can visualise the .tiff images downloaded from google earth engine.

Comment: You need to either share the image (using Google Drive, Dropbox or similar) or provide code or instructions that allow me/others to get it, else it is hard to help.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell: I have attached the code. Please help us out. Thanks!